# Store secrets in Travis, not in github repo

Tags: github, travis-ci, secret-key

I use this guide for ci, bumpversion, upload to pypi:

https://github.com/guettli/github-travis-bumpversion-pypi

I like it, except that the secret gets stored in the repo.

Example: https://github.com/guettli/reprec the file `secret-files.tar.enc` is in the git repo and it looks strange.

Open source lovers don't like unparsable binaries like this.

Is there a way to store the secret in travis instead of github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can set your secret as an environment variable on Travis, and use it in your program. Others can only know "oh, this guy uses a environment variable called `PASSWORD`!" and they don't know what the value is.

Only you and Travis CI know.

See this doc: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

If you want to store a secret file, you can create a private github repo, and clone it with your github password stored in the env variables.

Comment: This question is about storing a file in travis. The file is 10kByte. I guess storing binary data (tar file) is not supported.

Comment: @guettli Updated.

Comment: thank you for explaining the work-around (private github repo).